# NextJs app giving Page not found after deployed but locally it works perfectly

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, custom-error-pages, railway

As the title says, I recently deployed my app using Railway. I used railway before since am familiar with it and its easy to manage it.

When I deployed my next js app I am having the page not found error even though locally when I run it works. I read some documentation about possible migration of pages and app but I couldn't figure out how to fit that with my app. Also I am new to next js so maybe someone can help me out here?

This is how my folder structure looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAdK9.png)

And on railway everything checks out, I have no errors or warnings.

Thank you in advance

I excpect the app the run normally and for my page to be visible when its runing in production.

Comment: What is your NextJS version?

Comment: Hey sorry forgot to flag this as solved, I made it work, all I had to do is just change the watch path from defualt to src/pages**